# Track a custom event after install The App from Facebook Ads with google analytics

Tags: android, facebook, google-analytics

I want to track the installs that I am getting from Facebook ads using GA.
I'm using a dapp-ling url in facebook ads, so when app opens after installations I got the parameters and redirect to destination page.

What Im not getting here is, that Facebook shows X number of downloads in FB analytics page but my I'm getting only X/5 (approx) events in app.

As soon as user opens the app my event get registered on GA, I tested it(as FB suggested [from here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/?id=xxxx)), and it worked every time I open the app.

Please someone tell me what I'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

You counting different event types:
- FB counting number of downloads
- GA counting number of launches
In your case, you might have 5 users installed your app, but only 1 of them actually launch it.
Check you traffic sources in Google Play console against your FB campaign. It should match your FB report.